# Use global managed object contexts to support concurrency

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I haven't ever found an answer to this when reading developer documentation.

When using main and private queue contexts in `Core Data` is it a good strategy to use a global `NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType` and `NSMainQueueConcurrencyType` contexts that I can access across my app and for the entire lifetime of my app?

Or, should I be creating a new instance each time I need to use a `NSManagedObjectContext`?

I have used [this documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Concurrency.html) but it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Both are fine. I have had good experience using temporary background context, and bad experience using a global background context. Contexts are not expensive and you shouldn't be afraid to create and destroy them as needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most cases the current best practice is to start with `NSPersistentContainer`. Its methods point to good practices for dealing with managed object contexts.

`NSPersistentContainer` has a property `viewContext` which uses a main queue concurrency. As its name implies, it's good for use directly with the UI, and on the main queue. Use this context for those cases. Don't create new main queue contexts.

It also has a couple of ways to do background work on private queues, via `newBackgroundContext()` and `performBackgroundTask`. In most cases you can use either of these when you need to do background work, and not bother keeping a reference to a long-lived background context. One caveat is that since they use separate background queues, it's possible for one background context to be executing at the same time as another. If that seems possible in your case, you might want to hold onto a background context to avoid that possibility. Otherwise your background contexts might need to merge changes made on other background contexts, which can get ugly fast.

There are exceptions to all of the above, but this is a good starting point. If this doesn't fit with your app for some reason, come back with another question detailing why.

Comment: Isn't this the old way of doing background Core Data that Apple no longer recommends? I want to be using `NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType` and `NSMainQueueConcurrencyType`.

Comment: If you use either `newBackgroundContext()` or `performBackgroundTask`, you're using private queue concurrency.

Comment: Ah got it. This is all new in `iOS 10`.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to do write on a different context and then merge it back.

As a good practice i can recommend the setup [MagicalRecord](https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord) uses.

Specifically they use a [Default Context as a Child of a RootSavingContext](https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord/blob/master/MagicalRecord/Categories/NSManagedObjectContext/NSManagedObjectContext%2BMagicalRecord.m#L32). Then All writes go into a [new context](https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord/blob/94762ad5d8f57d508fd4d6c719bdcba18a36bf27/MagicalRecord/Core/MagicalRecord%2BActions.m#L23) and then get merged into the root context.

This way the default context can be used in the main thread and gets proper update notifications, e.g. for use with a FetchedResultsController.